# How to add an img to a html code block that is styled already

Tags: html, css, markdown

Answer what worked for me from Pimento Web: "Put you pre_code inside a div position relative. Put you image after you pre_code and position it with position absolute"

So I am trying to add a small image in the top right of code blocks produced by markdown (styled with ReadTheDocs). I am just going to write a script that drops in the appropriate image into the correct position in the html. But the one problem is that I do not know how to get the image in the position of an already styled code block. Is there an easy way to do this or am I opening up a huge can of worms? Much help would be appreciated for the sake of learning!

```html
<pre>
<code class ="JSON hljs"><img class="hiddenCopy" style ="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" src="../img/upload-script.png"/>var j =0;
</code>
</pre>
```

normally I would do something like this:

```html
<pre>
<code style="position: relative;"><img class="hiddenCopy" style ="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" src="../img/upload-script.png"/>var j =<span class="hljs-number">0</span>;
</code>
</pre>
```

and just have the code be relative with a position. But I do not want to modify the css of the code block as it is referencing an external website.
[Location of where I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0oco.png)

Comment: Put you pre_code inside a div position relative. Put you image after you pre_code and position it with position absolute...

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but what is "markdown-themeable"? There's many scripts that do this with similar names so I can't determine which one you're using

Comment: @DanyAlejandro my bad wrote the wrong one, updated, I meant Read The Docs

Comment: @PimentoWeb yah that worked. How do i pin comments as the accepted answer is the real question.

Comment: @yo76yo Tks that's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Explained in comment you can put your pre_code inside a div position relative.

Put your image after your pre_code and position it with position absolute, something maybe like this..

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <pre>
    <code class ="JSON hljs">var j =0;
    </code>
    </pre>
    <img class="hiddenCopy" style ="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" src="../img/upload-script.png"/>
</div>
```